# Swift3 Xcode8 - iOS app User profile data update and display in Profile Screen view

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, xcode8

First post and coding since 2 weeks, please be indulgent. Learning in the making.

It saves the users details correctly in Firebase under its own UID. My problem is that once the user logs out and log back in, the second party of the code under the override func viewDidLoad() is supposed to fetch the info available in the database and display them in the related text field, but it doesn't. Does anyone see anything madly wrong in the code below? Any solutions for this?

(sorry if the code hurt your eyes, I took bits and pieces around) Cheers for the help.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class EditProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var about = ["Name", "Email", "Phone", "Sex", "Profile Description", "Date of Birth"]
var user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

@IBAction func backAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func didTappedUpdateButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

var index = 0

    while index<about.count{

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        let cell: TextInputTableView? = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TextInputTableView?

        if cell?.myTextField.text != ""{

            let item:String = (cell?.myTextField.text!)!

            switch about[index]{

            case "Name":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Name").setValue(item)
            case "Email":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Email").setValue(item)
            case "Phone":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Phone").setValue(item)
            case "Sex":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Sex").setValue(item)
            case "Profile Description":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Profile Description").setValue(item)
            case "Date of Birth":
                self.ref.child("data/users").child("\(user!)/Date of Birth").setValue(item)

            default:
                print("Don't Update")
            }//end switch
        }//end if

        index+=1
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("data/users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let usersDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        print(usersDict)
        let userDetails = usersDict.object(forKey: self.user!)

        var index = 0

        while index<self.about.count{

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: index, section:0)
            let cell : TextInputTableView? = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TextInputTableView?

            let field: String = (cell?.myTextField.placeholder?.lowercased() )!

                switch field
                {
        case "Name":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Name") as? String, placeholder: "Name")
        case "Email":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Email") as? String, placeholder: "Email")
        case "Phone":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Phone") as? String, placeholder: "Phone")
        case "Sex":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Sex") as? String, placeholder: "Sex")
        case "Profile Description":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Profile Description") as? String, placeholder: "Profile Description")
        case "Date of Birth":
        cell?.configure(text: (userDetails as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Date of Birth") as? String, placeholder: "Date of Birth")

                default:
                    print("")

                }//end switch

            index+=1
        }
    })
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return about.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    let cell: TextInputTableView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextInput", for: indexPath) as! TextInputTableView

    cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "\(about[indexPath.row])")

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors thrown? Have you tried printing out the value of `usersDict `

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't work but it seems that the value printed is for all the users, it doesn't seems to print the one of current user... (hat will be a problem I guess with tens of millions of users :) ) 

Thanks for looking at it @EmilDavid !

Comment: No worries buddy..Can you post the structure of your database? Because I have a feeling that your current query doesn't exactly do what you think its doing

Comment: APP NAME
   ...data
        ...users   ( this is the UID similar from the Auth tab in Firebase console)
                  - fields
                  - fields
                  - fields

Apparently I'm not senior enough to post pic in my question so they created a link to it  http://i.stack.imgur.com/yYkWk.png
Have I messed up the Database structure ? @EmilDavid

Comment: Please clarify these two things for me. Your structure is appname/data/user/uid. Once inside uid you get details about that particular user right? And uh you want to pull the details of the currently logged in user right?

Comment: yes appname/data/user(UID)/ then under each user UID there is fields that the user can update as much as they want, but once updated they need to show up in each fields. can you see the picture in the link? @EmilDavid

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the silence. I was away from my laptop. These are my suggestions.

1. Get rid of the data node; it seems rather redundant. You can simply add other nodes under the root node i.e. *appname*.
2. Refractor your `viewDidLoad`; because its rather convoluted. Put the firebase retrieval stuff in a separate method.
3. Adopt a reusing habit. It makes your code less complex and easy to follow. This applies even with something as little as variables. e.g. you have `ref` declared globally; which is the way to go. But again you have another `ref` declared in your `viewDidLoad` and they both serve the same purpose. I know its a minor thing but why have multiple variables serving the same purpose?
4. You are not checking your result for any errors or `nil` values. You are directly unwrapping things. It is fine to directly unwrap things but this should only be done in places which you are 100% certain that you do have a value. For most internet queries, this is not the case and you want your app to handle those scenarios as well.

This is how I would have done it if I were you.
I made these two global variables:

```
var currentUser: FIRUser = FIRUser()
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Then I made this method which gets the user data just once. If you want it to get live updates, then simply change it from a `observeSingleEvent` to an `observe` instead and the type to either `.childAdded` or `.childChanged` depending on your specific scenario. I'll leave that challenge to you and everything else is the pretty much the same.

```
func getUserDetailsOnce()
{
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)

    // check first if the user is currently logged in. If yes, then save them in the variable user. Normally, you'd want to run this check inside your AppDelegate after didFinishLaunchWithOptions
    guard let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else
    {
        print("No logged user in existence")
        return
    }

    currentUser = user // update the global variable

    // append to the current user's node location
    databaseRef.child("data/users").child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        // you have retrieved the result and store it in firebaseValue. snapshot.value returns AnyObject?. Since its an optional it can be nil and we want to handle that scenario. And its highly advisable to cast it as a [String:AnyObject] instead of an NSDictionary
        guard let firebaseValue = snapshot.value as [String:AnyObject] else
        {
            print("Error with FrB snapshot") // this is printed if no Firebase value is returned
            return
        }

        // Now that we have our value, we can access the respective elements

        let index = 0

        while index < self.about.count
        {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

            // This is where I am a little bit puzzled as to how you have your cell structured. But if you want to access the individual elements inisde our database then you simply have to check for nils for each individual component as shown below

            guard let email = firebaseValue["email"] as? String, let name = firebaseValue["name"] as? String else // add the other ones respectively
            {
                print("Error extracting individual Firebase components")
                return
            }

            // Then you can display the values since they are now stored in the variables email,name etc

            index += 1
        }
    }
}
```